# android: Web view doesn't support html5 content?

Tags: android, jquery-mobile

I displayed the HTML5 content using web view in android, but properties (like data-role, data-theme) of  HTML5 are not applied to the content, meaning that the HTML5 content isn't displayed in the WebView.

I want to display the HTML5 content (using jQuery mobile) - please can anybody help me?

Comment: Did you enabled javascript in your WebView?

Comment: I added the answer with the code you need

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
    myWebView.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
```